# How do you get python to print line with most words in and stop repeating print?

Tags: python

```
a=input("Please enter your problem?")
problem = a.split(' ')
max_num, current_num = 0,0 
chosen_line = ''

with open('solutions.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        for word in problem:
            if word in line:
                current_num+=1
        if current_num>max_num:
            max_num=current_num
            chosen_line = line
            print (chosen_line)
        else:
            print ("please try again")
```

This code prints all the lines in the text file however I need it only to print the line with most words, that the user has entered in. Also if it doesn't find any words that the user has entered in the it should display 'please try again', however it displays it 7 times

Comment: I don't see any code approaching the task you describe.

Comment: To stop a loop, you use `break`. But you don't want that. You just don't need to be printing anything within the loop over the lines

Answer (score 0):

You are currently accumulating a counter of how many relevant words a line contains, then saving that value in a different counter and printing the line. Instead, you will need to count words in each line and save the line with the best result so that you can print it at the end.

```
a = input("Please enter your problem?")
problem = set(a.split())
max_relevance = 0
best_line = ''

with open('solutions.txt') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        relevance = sum(word in problem for word in line.split())
        if relevance > max_relevance:
            best_line = line

print(best_line or "please try again")
```

Comment: you my friend are a genius

Answer (score -1):

```
a=input("Please enter your problem?")
problem = set(a.split(' '))
max_num, current_num = 0,0 
chosen_line = ''

with open('solutions.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        current_num = sum( 1 for item in line if item in problem)
        if current_num > max_num:
            chosen_line = line
            max_num = current_num

print chosen_line
```

Comment: Thanks however it does not print anything also I need it to print 'sorry' if can find any words.

Comment: This has bugs, and no attempt at explanation.